# Adding Default Constraints to table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I am working with PostgreSQL database.  I have created the required tables. Now I have to alter table columns as per constraints. I have to apply default constraint to one of my columns whose default value should be 1.

This is the query I am using,

```
ALTER TABLE Alerts ADD  CONSTRAINT DF_Alerts_bIsActive SET DEFAULT ((1)) FOR bIsActive;
```

This is the error I am Getting,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET"
LINE 30: ... TABLE Alerts ADD  CONSTRAINT DF_Alerts_bIsActive SET DEFAUL...
                                                              ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 948
```

Please can anyone suggest me the proper way to achieve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "default constraint". You simply define default *values*.

```
alter table alerts alter column bisactive set default 1;
```

---

Unrelated, but: 
`bisactive` sounds like that is some kind of flag. You should define that as a proper `boolean` column, not an integer.

Comment: In fact interestingly enough in MS SQL Server there is such thing as *default constraint*, and the syntax in the question relates to that. Things are sometimes strange in MS world.